# use textbox value in javascript alert

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have wrote this code

```
string javaScript = "<script language=JavaScript>\n" + "alert('Form Submitted Successfully!');\n" + "</script>";

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Button1_ClickScript", javaScript);
```

but I want to put a textbox value in the message.

How can I do that

Comment: Do you mean the alert, you want the textbox value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you wanted to build the message with server side code - something like this:

```
string javaScript = "<script language='JavaScript'>alert('Textbox value " + Server.HtmlEncode(txtYourTextBox.Text) + "');</script>";

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Button1_ClickScript", javaScript);
```

Comment: Everything he wants is already on the client, why go to the server?  Just because processing is cheap we shouldn't abuse it.

Comment: @Chizl Unfortunately the question doesn't give us any real insight to the coding situation so I'm simply presenting a different answer to whats been answered already.

Comment: @SouravSarkar interesting its untested but its simply the same code you posted, amended so that the alerts message is built on the server. The 2nd line (RegisterStartupScript) hasn't been amended only the first line. Perhaps there's something in the textbox's value that is causing the javascript to fail - encoding the text value might help, example amended to reflect this

Comment: @ Chris Moutray
Thanks you so much sir
It Works perfectly.
Hats off to you.
HtmlEncode works!
Thanks you so much

Answer (score 3):

Give the textbox (or better, HTML `<input>` tag) an id:

```
 <input name="mytext" id="theId" value="somevalue">
```

and refer it as such:

```
 alert(document.getElementById("theId").value);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your alert you can reference the element via the forms collection:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(document.forms[0].elements["myTextBox"].value)
</script>
```

And your textbox:

```
<textbox id="myTextBox"></textbox>
```

Comment: alert(document.forms['MyFormName'].elements["myTextBox"].value)